# Access service deployed on Kubernetes with domain name instead of external ip address

Tags: kubernetes, service, dns, cloud, hostname

I am running one service of type LoadBalancer on K8 cluster, which is serving external rest requests. With LoadBalancer I can access the service with external IP Address. But we need fixed domain name for accessing services with ease. I tried solving this with provider given specification (Gardener) but this is not helping us as we want to make this provider independent. basically the domain name (or combination of hostname, namespace, subdomain name, domain name) we define should work with any cloud providers. Is it feasible?

Comment: external-dns supports multiple providers https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns

Comment: Also check helm chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/external-dns Would this be your solution?